# Question pertaining to the number of possible worlds in many worlds interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

So I’ve been reading about the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics, and I keep seeing that they say that all worlds would come about. In repeatedly seeing the notion of all options, I wondered, could you have seemingly absurd outcomes where things like life history had this elaborate design in it. Just to clarify what I mean, lets say something like there is a highly detailed symmetrical design where two very prominent nations live a detailed history whose intricate specifics mirror a pattern of ABCDDCBA, or another example would be multiple highly detailed and elaborate religious prophecies that just would have to be fulfilled because all options are present.

It’s my feeling that this isn’t possible because I think that I would see musings like this if it were, but I keep reading all worlds, so I’m not 100 percent sure.

Additionally, even if it’s not possible for the many worlds interpretation, could any of the multiverse theories realize something like this?

Comment: could you share the reference that you read about the many-worlds interptretation?

Comment: To be honest, I've read quite a few, so I was just going to cite wikipedia. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation

"This implies that all possible outcomes of quantum measurements are physically realized in some "world" or universe."

I will say though that reading that comment made me wonder if it's going to amount to that even though all possible measurements of quantum outcomes would be realized, that doesn't mean that quantum outcomes have every theoretical possibility at their disposal. Is this accurate?

Comment: However, then I read comments like this, "Max Tegmark has affirmed that absurd or highly unlikely events are inevitable but rare under the MWI. To quote Tegmark, "Things inconsistent with the laws of physics will never happen—everything else will... it's important to keep track of the statistics, since even if everything conceivable happens somewhere, really freak events happen only exponentially rarely."", which came from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation#Absurdly_improbable_timelines , and then I'm not sure again.